# Round a value to two decimal places in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to round a value in SQL, here is the code that I have:

```
select round(600.000,2)
```

How do I get the value `600.00`?

Comment: Which database are you using? `round` is working correctly, but it does not format the number. Formatting is probably best done by the receiver of the data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of a complete lack of effort by the OP do try to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `round()` convert to a decimal:

```
select cast(600.000 + 0.5 as decimal(10, 2) )
```

`round()` changes the *value* but it might not change the type of the result.  Hence, you might still see extra decimal points (depending on the database and the application).  Converting to a `decimal` with two digits of precision converts both the value and the type.

Comment: Just want to add that if this is currency, you can also do this: `SELECT CAST(600.000 AS MONEY)` and cast it to a `MONEY` type.